# Sudden drop in all RabbitMQ queue acks

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

I see some strange behavior in all my Rabbitmq queues. As you can see in the screenshot at some intervals all queue ack/publish rates drop and again get back to normal. I see nothing unusual in CPU and RAM usage, what could be the problem?

I use RabbitMQ 3.8.14 with Erlang 23.2.7.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If the average time that a message stays in the queue is 5 minutes, the drop in the ack rates is caused by the drop in the publish rates. Can you share the publisher & consumers code?

Comment: The cosumers are usally fast (5ms for each message) and the code is just two applications that are spring amqp clients that use rpc. This happens on all my queues with different applications.

Comment: You can have a ttl queue with an dead-letter exchange in order to apply a delay to every message regardless of the actual consume time, but I guess that it's not the case. Can you include both the deliver rates and the legend in the image?

Comment: There are many factors at play here, and It may very well be on the producer or consumer side. First thing I'd try to obtain the publish & consume rates from both the producer and consumer and use wireshark to try to find what's happening around that time (although with 1k m/s it's going to be tedious). This information would be useful to determine if the issue is in RMQ or the producer/consumer code